# Search words only with capitalize

Tags: php

I have text:

`$cnt = "Hello, kiss this please Elona.";`

I have code:

```
$ac_repl = mb_convert_case('elona', MB_CASE_TITLE,'UTF-8');
if(stripos($cnt, $ac_repl) === false) //it's true! Why??
    continue;
```

How I can find word with capitalize text transform? 
My code is not working.

Comment: what is $cnt in this code?

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Right well that will match, so yeah it should be non-false. That's as per spec.

Comment: How I can fix? Can you talk me?

Comment: well you haven't said what you want it to do instead, I don't understand your request. It is finding Elona in the text because that's what you asked it to find. What did you want to happen?

Comment: No. I need check, if in text I search Elona with first latter uppercase, then should be true, if elona with first letter small, then false.

Comment: see the answer below. stripos() is not case-sensitive. Use strpos() instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code:

```
$cnt     = "Hello, kiss this please Elona.";
$cnt2    = "Hello, kiss this please elona.";
$ac_repl = mb_convert_case('elona', MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8');

var_dump(stripos($cnt, $ac_repl));  // dumps int(24)
var_dump(strpos($cnt2, $ac_repl)); // dumps bool(false)
```

The [*stripos*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)  function is **not case-sensitive**, the [*strpos*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) is